# Return pointer to nested inner class from generic outer class

Tags: c++, templates, nested-class

I'm new to C++, so bear with me.  I have a generic class called A.  A has a nested class called B.  A contains a method called getB(), which is supposed to return a new instance of B.   However, I can't get my code to compile.  Here's what it looks like:#include

A.h

```
template <class E>
class A {

public:
    class B {
    public:
        int data;
    };

    B * getB(); 
};
```

A.cpp

```
#include "A.h"

template <class E>
A<E>::B * A::getB() {
    return new B();
}
```

When I try to compile this, I get the following error:

```
error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '*' token
```

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks,

helixed

UPDATE:

Thanks for the quick replies everyone.  I'm still having a little trouble getting this working.  After taking the suggestions listed here, I have something like this:

A.h

```
template <class E>
class A {

public:
    class B {
    public:
        int data;
    };

    B * getB(); 
};

template <class E>
typename A<E>::B * A<E>::getB() {
    return new B();
}

class C {

};
```

However, when I try to use this from main, I get an error.  Here's my main method:

main.cpp

```
#include "A.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    A<C> *a = new A<C>();
    A<C>::B *b = a.getB();
}
```

When I try to compile this, I get the following error:

```
error: request for member 'getB' in 'a', which is of non-class type 'A<C>*'
```

Thanks again for the quick responses.

helixed

Comment: Hmm, works on Comeau. But even if this compiled, would it help? The definition for getB would only be available in A.cpp. Since it's a template, it then couldn't be called from any other translation unit unless your compiler supports "export".

Comment: Response to edit: use `->` for member access via pointer.

Comment: Oh, duh, I feel really stupid now.  I've spent too much time in Java.  Thanks for the help Steve.

Comment: No worries. Btw, for class templates I generally just define the functions in the class definition. Unless you're dealing with mutual dependencies between classes (meaning that there need to be some more definitions in between the class and the function), there's no benefit in using the code you've got rather than just `class A { ... B* getB() { return new B(); } ... };`.

Comment: I wrote this as a quick example to illustrate the problem I was having.  My real piece of code is a little more involved, and I was trying to avoid a ton of inlined code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The compiler isn't smart enough to figure that "B" is a type when "A" is templated.  Try using typename.

```
template <class E>
typename A<E>::B * A<E>::getB() {
    return new B();
}
```

Comment: And as Steve Jessop mentioned, keep it in the .h file, not the .cc file.

Comment: This seemed to fix the original problem.  However, I'm still having a little bit of trouble, as I've posted above.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Use: "A<C>::B *b = a->getB();"  You need to dereference the "a" pointer.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `typename` in your definition to hint to the compiler that B is a type.

```
template <class E>
typename A<E>::B * A::getB() {
   return new B;
}
```

Comment: I see your point.  I've moved the definition into the A.h file.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to the update:

You don't need to `new` everything in C++, in fact, it would be best if you did not, since then you would have to explicitly `delete` the memory allocated or use smart pointers.

So, here is your code revised:

```
template <class E>
class A {

public:
    class B {
    public:
        int data;
    };

    B getB(); // Object, not pointer
};

template <class E>
typename A<E>::B A<E>::getB() {
    return B();
}

#include "A.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    A<C> a = A<C>();
    A<C>::B b = a.getB();
}
```

If you wish to `new` the `A<C>` class, then you need to use the `operator->` to invoke methods:

```
A<C>::B b = a->getB();
```